HTML CSS Support extension in VsCode isn't giving Bootstrap property hints for styling
I've seen someone using the extension HTML CSS Support within VScode in this way:
type in a tag>give it a class w/ Bootstrap styles> and then be shown a dropdown of Bootstrap-relavent property hints.
Example - Typing in their index.html file :
< div class="container-fluid bg-" >
gave them a dropdown of Bootstrap property hints such as bg-warning, bg-success, bg-light...etc
Yet for me, having the same HTML CSS Support extension installed, I can't seem to get these hints to populate.
I've tried the typical reload VScode and restart it all together, as well as googling, but I couldn't find an answer specific or really relevant to my issues.
Any tips would be appreciated ^.^

Hey daymen, you can use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion

Thank you!! This worked. I appreciate it :)

This works, and was the solution to the issue. Thanks @ProgrammerGaurav
